# angular - dynamically add input filed linked to gereric key-value array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this generic key value array

`cost: {[ key: string ] : number};`

I'm trying to figure out how to set a simple dynamic input field

```
<input name="costCat" [(ngModel)] = "???"/>
<input name="costVal" [(ngModel)] = "???"/>
```

to be incremented dynamically with a button depending on how many cost category I have.

The goal is to get an object similar to this:

```
'{"everyone":"10"}'
```

or even this

```
'{"young":"free", "adult":10, "elderly":"free"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-field-kgg6fw/?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) solution:

ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Dynamic Add Fields';
  values = [];
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  removevalue(i){
    this.values.splice(i,1);
  }
  
  addvalue(k:string){
    this.values.push({key:k,value: ""});
  }
  
}
```

html file

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values; let i = index"> 
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value.key" #name="ngModel" name="value{{i}}">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value.value" #name="ngModel" name="value{{i}}">
  <button (click)="removevalue(i)">Remove</button>
</div>
<button (click)="addvalue('')">ADD</button>


<h2>Result</h2>
<div *ngFor="let value of values;">
  {{ value.key }}:{{value.value}}
</div>
```